# Change default behavior of "New ASP.NET Project"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, authentication

Whenever I create a new ASP.NET MVC project, I get this dialog:

[image]

The one thing I almost *always* have to change is the authentication (to "None") - either it's jsut a test web that I'm creating and it needs no authentication, or for the case of a "real world" web app, I need to handle authentication in a custom fashion myself, so I really hardly ever need the "Individual User Accounts" that are presented as the default.

Is there a registry setting or some configuration setting somewhere that would allow me to define "No Authentication" to be the default, whenever this dialog pops up??

This is for .NET 4.0 and newer, and Visual Studio 2013 and newer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used to help me in a lot questions.
Anyway, for this case, depend on the Visual Studio version / language / template, the directory may different:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WebTemplates\MVC\CSharp\1033\Templates.xml`

The above directory is for Visual Studio 2015 - C# Web Template

From here, you can change the default authentication:

```
<Authentication Default="NoAuth">    
    <NoAuth/>
    <IndividualAuth/>
    <WindowsAuth/>
    <OrgAuth/>
</Authentication>
```